# How to get the active module as object

Tags: python, module

When you import another python-file the variable with the same name is assigned with a module-object:

```
>>> import somemodule
>>> somemodule
<module 'somemodule' from '/home/code/test/somemodule.py'>
```

But how do you get the active module as an object in `somemodule.py` itsself, which should be the same object as the variable `somemodule` in `<stdin>`?

Comment: You don't need to. Within the module, you have access to the module object's contents through its global variables.

Comment: I know that, but the module itsself should be passed to a function using some module-object to register specific objects of it.

Comment: `import sys    
print(sys.modules['__main__'])`  gives a reference, but i'm not sure if the object returned is what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of the current module from `__name__`. That name will look something like `package.module` (assuming your file is in package/module.py).

Use that string to access the module inside `sys.modules` but beware: you don't want to do this while the module load is in progress! While your module's outermost level code is being run, the module definitions are still in a state of flux -- you can't necessarily count on always being able to access everything.

For specific example, the module statements are executed top to bottom. So if you access the module in the middle, any variables and functions defined above the access will be in the module, but things defined below the access will not have been executed, and so won't be in the module yet. Whoops!